# Overlap in the fpdf output in php

Tags: php, fpdf

Iam a beginner in using fdpf in php . I have searched a lot but couldn't find the solution

I need to get output like this

[image: expected output]

but the output of my code is

[image: current output]

the code:

```
$row1a=mysql_fetch_array($sql_1a);
$row1b=mysql_fetch_array($sql_1b);
$row1c=mysql_fetch_array($sql_1c);

$pdf->Cell(6,6," 1 a) ",0,0);
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();  
$pdf->MultiCell(150,6,"{$row1a['Question']}",0,1);
$pdf->SetXY($x + 160, $y);
$pdf->Cell(6,6,"{$row1a['Mark']}",0,1);

$pdf->Cell(6,6," b) ",0,0);
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();          
$pdf->MultiCell(150,6,"{$row1b['Question']}",0,1);
$pdf->SetXY($x + 160, $y);
$pdf->Cell(6,6,"{$row1b['Mark']}",0,1);

$pdf->Cell(6,6," c) ",0,0);
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();  
$pdf->MultiCell(150,6,"{$row1c['Question']}",0,1);
$pdf->SetXY($x + 160, $y);
$pdf->Cell(6,6,"{$row1c['Mark']}",0,1);
```

where $row1a,$row1b,$row1c are the variables used to fetch the question and marks from database. 
Since the question can be of variable length fetched from database , it overlaps with the next question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer from @Luthando should working, but if want' the alternative you can do that by using WriteHTML which you can write your view in HTML code, for simple way you can use table in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

try this on the overlapping row:

```
$height =  round(strlen($row1b['Question']) / 35);
$height = ($height < 1 ? 1 : $height);
$height = $height * 6;

$pdf->MultiCell(150,$height,"{$row1b['Question']}",0,1);
```

Comment: could you tell me why is it divided by 35 in the first line?

Comment: you can do it anyway you want, I assumed you will only want a line to have a length of 35 characters

Answer (score 0):

Perform a `GetY()` update after every `MultiCell()` call (this pushes the current Y value every time downwards) and recalculate it properly for every further `MultiCell()`.