# FPDF overlapping variable

Tags: php, fpdf

I am down to my finial problem with my script, everything works but i can't get multicell to work. Each time i apply the multicell to description, text goes everywhere and does not break on the 2nd line.

I just have some descriptions that are about 20% longer then the design PDF and i just need to limit the variable and add a line break as the below example.

Now i found this which looks like a good solution [Overlap in the fpdf output in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193626/overlap-in-the-fpdf-output-in-php)

I just tried applying the above and again it threw text about and still not able to design a function that will

```
if($Total1!=0)
{
// Column Title
$pdf->Text('8','68','F01U');
$pdf->Text('38','68','Model');
$pdf->Text('68','68','Description');
$pdf->Text('158','68','TradePrice');
$pdf->Text('178','68','QTY');
$pdf->Text('193','68','Total');

// Form Products set 1
$pdf->Text('8','74',$F01u1);
$pdf->Text('38','74',$Model1);
$pdf->Text('68','74',$Description1);
$pdf->Text('158','74',$TradePrice1);
$pdf->Text('178','74',$Qty1);
$pdf->Text('193','74',$Total1);
}

// Form Products Set 2
if($Total2!=0)
{
    $pdf->Text('8','86',$F01u2);
    $pdf->Text('38','86',$Model2);
    $pdf->Text('68','86',$Description2);
    $pdf->Text('158','86',$TradePrice2);
    $pdf->Text('178','86',$Qty2);
    $pdf->Text('193','86',$Total2);
}
```

Comment: Post your full code maybe can help to understand your stack..